# Sheldon Axler 7.30: How to verify example 7.30

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have trouble in verifying example 7.30 as the following in Linear Algebra Done Right (Third Edition).

> 7.30 Example: Consider the self-adjoint operator $T$ on $R^3$ whose matrix(with respect to the standard basis) is
>
> $$
> \left(\begin{array}{cc}
> 14 & -13 & 8 \\
> -13 & 14 & 8 \\
> 8 & 8 & -7
> \end{array} \right).
> $$
>
> As you can verify,
>   $$
> \frac{ \left( 1, -1, 0 \right) }{ \sqrt 2 }, 
> \frac{ \left( 1, 1, 1 \right) }{ \sqrt 3 },
> \frac{ \left( 1, 1, -2 \right) }{ \sqrt 6 }
> $$ 
>   is an orthonormal basis of $R^3$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$, and with respect to this basis, the matrix of $T$ is the diagonal matrix
>
> $$
> \left(\begin{array}{cc} 
> 27 & 0 & 0 \\
> 0 & 9 & 0 \\
> 0 & 0 & -15
> \end{array} \right).
> $$

I'm new in linear algebra, and I guess it might be very simple. But I still don't know how to verify it. 
Maybe my fundamental problem is, I don't know, how will the matrix of the linear map be changed with an basis to another basis?

Comment: In 10.7 we will have a "change of basis formula" and you can use that to verify.

Comment: Thanks, Hongyi. Then I'll go over 10.7 first and come back verify 7.30.

Comment: Section 10.7 is not necessary to verify Example 7.30. Just show that the matrix above times the first vector equals 27 times the first vector, that the matrix above times the second vector equals 9 times the second vector, and the matrix above times the third vector equals -15 times the third vector. Then use the definition of the matrix of a linear map with respect to a basis to get the desired conclusion.

Comment: Thanks, professor Sheldon. I'm so honored to get your personal answer. I get it now.

Comment: For those who dont recall the specifics of professor Axler answer, go to 3.65 of Linear Algebra Done right, 3rd edition.